# Showing iterations and using the Maclaurin expansion of e^x

Tags: matlab, if-statement

I have been trying to use persistent variables and the idea of showing each iteration here but I cannot get the code to work. I would really appreciate some help! 
The aim of the function is to iteratively calculate partial sums of the Maclaurin Expansion of f(x) = e^x for a given x and show to results in the command window once running.

```
function ex = Exp_series(x) 
   persistent n ee;
   % declare variables that will be carried to the next call
   if isempty(n) || isempty(ee)
      % initiate the persisten value
      n = 0;
      ee = 1;
   else
      n = n+1;
      ee = ee+x^n/factorial(n);
   end
   ex = ee;
end
```

Comment: Just use a for loop. But you haven't asked a specific question here.

Comment: looks OK. You use `persistent` correctly. Now put the whole function in a loop as Daniel said